# The right HTTP code for correct URL address but resource not found

Tags: http, http-status-code-404, error-code

Assuming we have an HTTP endpoint to get a `cat` by its name:

GET `.../cat?name=Oscar`

How to distinguish in the HTTP response code between a situation where the application could not find `Oscar` vs situations that the caller entered a wrong URL (e.g. `cats` and not `cat`).

As a developer that consumes the data from the HTTP endpoint I like to quickly know if I misspelled the URL or the resource itself is not there.

Should both of these situations return 404 (Not found) error?

Looking at the [list of HTTP statuses](https://www.restapitutorial.com/httpstatuscodes.html) I don't see a way to distinguish between the two situations.

Answer (score 0):

The query part is part of the URL. If you specify a query for something that does not exist, then 404 clearly is the correct reply.